# Remove huge amount of files

Tags: php, linux

I have 8 millions of files in my /tmp and I need to remove them. This server is also running pretty important app and I can not overload it.

I'm using small php script:

```
<?php
$dir = "/tmp";
$dh = opendir( $dir);
$i = 0;
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
  $file = "$dir/$file";
  if (is_file( $file) && (preg_match("/open/", $file))) {
    unlink( $file);
    #echo $file;
    if (!(++$i % 10000)) {
      echo "$i files removed\n";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

but it makes my app unreachable, even with:
$ ionice -c 3 php ./tmp_files_killer.php
$ nice -n 20 php ./tmp_files_killer.php

I've changed my script so it wouldn't read /tmp dir all the time:

```
$ ls -1 /tmp > tmp_files_list.txt

<?php
$file = "tmp_files_list.txt"; 
$infile = fopen($file, "r"); 

while ( !feof( $infile ) ) { 
  $line = rtrim( fgets( $infile ), "\n\r" ); 
  if ($line != null){ 
    $file = "$dir/$line";
    unlink( $file);
    if (!(++$i % 10000)) {
      echo "$i files removed\n";
    }
#    echo $line + "\n";
  } 
} 
?>
```

but running this script also slows down my app. Process doesn't load CPU and I have enough of memory.

Guys, how to delete these files?

Comment: Can't you do it on the command line? Do you have to delete them just once, or in regular intervals? Perhaps creating a cronjob which deletes a fixed amount of files at regular intervals.

Answer (score 4):

You could get the script to operate in "chunks", then sleep between each chunk.

In your second version, you could add a sleep() in after the echo, say 30 seconds. If you tune the number of files deleted and the time slept, it should keep the server responsive while still performing adequately.

In future, you should run a cleanup job regularly from cron to stop yourself from getting to this point.

Answer (score 3):

if you can directly execute commands on linux terminal then this will become very easy process, directly execute this command

```
find /tmp -type f -exec rm -v {} \;
```

additionally if you want to carry out this process periodically then you can configure a cronjob to run at midnight where your server will almost be idle

Comment: I would also try this first - but it may still hammer the server.

Comment: Note that this will miss files that do not have a `.` in their name.

Comment: .. Also, the `-exec ` will cause about a thousand times or more `execve(2)` system calls than it needs to. `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 rm` would execute `rm` significantly less often. And the output (`-v`) is just going to cause needless IO, which is often the slowest part of programs...

Comment: yes `-v` is added just for debugging so you can see which files are deleted in terminal, you can remove it if you don't want it

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this a different way: destroy the entire filesystem in one go.

Create a new filesystem -- it could be a simple `tmpfs` filesystem, it could be an ext2 or ext3 filesystem living in a file that is loopback mounted, it could be a new drive (USB memory stick?), anything.

Then `mv` the `/tmp` mount point to another name, mount your new filesystem on `/tmp`, and then run `mke2fs` on the *partition* that used to be `/tmp`, and write a whole new clean filesystem from scratch.

Once your old-tmp device is re-created, you can perform the steps again -- `mv /tmp /new-tmp`, copy off data that should be persistent, `mount` the re-formatted device back on `/tmp,`, and copy back the data that should persist.

Answer (score 0):

I did this kind of stuff when I wanted to clean an upload dir for a gallery. It was really long... So I decided to give a try to `exec()`  like commands with the command `rm /path/to/clean/*` and it got really fast.

Not very clean, but at least, it worked good for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a need to do the cleanup by using a php script?

If not, take a look at this [article](http://linuxgazette.net/issue18/tmp.html)...should get you a few ideas

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the faster still standard way to remove all files under /tmp:

```
find /tmp -type f -exec rm {} +
```

With Gnu find, this might be slightly faster:

```
find /tmp -type f -delete
```

If /tmp is on its own file system, just unmount and mkfs it. If it is tmpfs, just reboot.